# Can't list window.document properties - why?

Tags: javascript, object-properties

Running this JavaScript lists in Firefox 60.2 only one property ("location"), but there are many others, like "document.title" etc.

```js
window.console.log("List props: " + Object.keys(window.document).sort().join(' / '));
```

Why is it this way? Safety? How is this done technically?
How can I list all properties?

Comment: Just log `document`, and you'll get all the properties.

Comment: No. Even in Chrome 67.0 on Windows 10 only the property "location" is listed, nothing else. And no, using only "document" instead of "window.document" changes nothing at all.

Comment: ?? I can see all the properties in FF (60.0.2) console ... `Object.keys` returns only "_the enumerable's own properties_", all the properties in `document` are not enumerable nor own, though there are much more own enumerable properties than `location` only. Maybe a bit poor wording in my first comment, I meant do `console.log(document)`, that'll show you all the properties.

Comment: Yes! Your last comments explains what happens, thanks! Using the console was only used for reproducing the problem, but I need a more versatile solution - which is shown in an answer below.

Comment: Hmm ... There really  seems not to be more than that single own property, MDN's [Document documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) is a bit misleading, it lists the properties as they were the own properties ...

Answer (score 2):

`Object.keys(o)` returns the *own, enumerable* properties of `o`.

- *Own*: properties defined directly on `o`, not on its [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain):
- *Enumerable*: a flag that controls if a given property is included when listing an object's properties.

In this case most of the keys you expect are defined on another object in in `document`'s [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain):

```
document.hasOwnProperty("title"); // false
document.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("title"); // true
document.__proto__.__proto__.propertyIsEnumerable("title"); // true
```

You can use a `for... in` loop to find the enumerable properties that are defined on an object *or* its prototype chain:

```
for (let key in window.document) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: For some time your answer was deleted.Why?

Comment: Yes, it was invisible for a short time - I wondered, too.
Possibly my comment wasn't ok, because it does not clarified the problem, but was only a praise :-) Or a caching phenomenon?

Comment: I wrote an answer quickly, then realised it had a factual inaccuracy so I deleted it whilst I checked and edited, then undeleted.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an official reason for it not working with window.document but it seems you can reproduce this behavior with other variables as well.
The issue *seems to be* `Object.keys()` not returning everything from these variables.

If you're still trying to get all properties of document, you can still use

```
var props = [];
for(var prop in window.document) {
    props.push(prop);
}
console.log("List props: " + props.sort().join('/'));
```

Which will do the exact same thing as your approach.

Comment: This is not an issue with object.keys it is how it works

Comment: Object.keys() returns an array of strings that represent all the enumerable properties of the given object.

Comment: @ManosKounelakis [The `for...in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), which is exactly like you described `Object.keys()`. So please tell me, if your definition of `Object.keys()` is the same as the MDA definition of `for...in`, then why does one of them return all attributes and the other in some cases just two of them?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `Object.keys()` returns returns an array of strings that represent all the enumerable properties of the given object.
Try this to see which properties of document are enumerable

```js
for(let key in document){
  let isEnumerable  = document.propertyIsEnumerable(key);
  console.log(`docment['${key}'] isEnumerable?:${isEnumerable}`);
}
```

However as the previous answer has stated you can use a for-in loop to get all properties in an array sort them and join them